# How to express a chronological dependency?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, word-order

How do I express a chronological dependency between two events? Is it alright to say :

> "Event A must be chronologically after Event B"?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow, postdate and succeed are antonyms of precede.

The meaning of postdate is different from what you seek, so you are left with

- *Event A must **follow** Event B*
- *Event A must **succeed** Event B*

Though the meaning is not strictly the same to your example, as both of these also imply that Event A causes Event B, where your original statement does not. Therefore, the same meaning would be

- *Event A, if it occurs, must **occur after** Event B*

Chronologically is implied with after.

Finally, to say

- *Event B can not **precede** Event A*

would mean the same as original statement.

Answer (score 1):

Events, by definition, *take place*, (rather than just existing), which automatically locates them in time.   So saying "Event A must take place after Event B" is both idiomatic and precise.

Comment: It is not so precise, it is rather ambiguous; it can mean 1) Event B implies Event A i.e. every time Event B occurs it will cause Event A to occur  2) Event A always occurs chronologically after Event B, but does not need to occur every time Event B occurs

Comment: @Unreason: It's ambiguous about whether B always implies A but that wasn't what the question asked; it is totally unambiguous about the fact that A requires B.

Comment: @Mr. Shiny, *exactly*! And... since OP did not specify what is it that original statement is trying to convey it is not clear if the answer is adequate.